# Choosing Among Multiply Imputed Datasets

Tags: missing-data, convergence, multiple-imputation

I am using multiple imputation to estimate treatment effects in a dataset that contains missing data. In some of my imputed datasets, the algorithm used in the analysis fails to converge; it's not simply that there are not enough iterations, but there is no real solution (e.g., the estimation surface is saddle-shaped).

Is it justifiable to only report the results from the datasets where the analysis converged? Should I continue to generate imputed datasets until I have as many with converged estimates as the number of imputations I originally proposed?

My fear is that by selecting among my imputed datasets on this criterion (i.e., whether the analysis converges on a solution), I am introducing bias into the estimates (a selection bias). On the other hand, if I can assume that the convergence of the analysis is unrelated to the effect that would be estimated, removing imputations (and replacing them), I would assume, would not introduce this bias. But can I justify that the failure to converge is unrelated to the estimate?

Comment: One critical detail is missing: Why did the algorithm converge for some imputations and not for others? If this is somehow related to the data, then using only the successful imputations introduces a novel type of informative missingness.

Comment: That's exactly my thought. Unfortunately, I don't know why the algorithm failed. It obviously has something to do with the unique combination of imputed values in that dataset. Is there a diagnostic I could use to test whether the failure to converge is informative?